# How To Disable Browser Back Button In Custom AMP Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, amp-html, ampscript

last time i put this custom disable browser back button (Javascript) in my AMP websites page ( [websites](https://www.luckysanto.com/) ).

I use this script to reduce the bounce rate in seo. But after requesting indexing in google search console i got some problem with "There is a required attribute missing from the HTML tag" in this script.

Does anyone know what is the solution to disable this browser back button script on AMP Pages?

`<script type = "text/javascript" > history.pushState(null, null); window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) { history.pushState(null, null); }); </script>`

By the way, my page is fully custom html AMP page, so all my css, html, scripts are concatenated inside index.html file.

Websites: [luckysanto.com](https://www.luckysanto.com/)

Comment: You really shouldn't try to change browser behavior because that results in a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a valid AMP page? As I can see your script is non-AMP so probably it's deleted by amp sanitizer. You have to run your custom JavaScript in a Web Worker in order to have a valid AMP page. Here is [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script) component documentation.

Since you can only run JS in the web worker (in other words isolated DOM), you cannot manipulate anything outside of it, most likely browser history too.